# Mobile First Server 8.0 connection check from client side

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Need to check whether MFP server up and running, if server not reachable, need to alert user that system is down.

i have used the below code

```
renderer.listen('document', 'mfpjsloaded', () => {
  WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("").then(
  function(accessToken) {
    console.log("MFP Server is up and running");       
 },
 function(error) {
   console.log("MFP Server is not reachable");
 }
);
```

});

but app throws  `Application Error The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`

Comment: can you please update with console/server log

Comment: couldnt see anything in log also, before it reaches the FAILURE. App throws that error

Comment: at least take a screenshot of your error that displaying on mobile and post it.

Comment: The error callback provides you with a detailed error message. Provide the error message 
`function(error) {
   console.log("MFP Server is not reachable" + JSON.stringofy(error) );
 }`

Comment: obtainAccessToken() connects to the server and gets you a token. Then on, as long as the token is valid, it does not re-make a call to the server.
For the current error, post the output of the error callback

Comment: am getting "Failed to connect to IPADDRESS", how to differentiate whether SERVER is down or Adapter failed due to network drop ?

Comment: What JSON.stringofy(error) says ? this would  help you to differentiate .

Comment: Is there any document or link to check the ERR CODE and ERR MESSAGE in MFP 8.0 ?